# Getting an overflow error within unchecked statement

Tags: c#

```
byte b;
int i;

unchecked
{
    b = 255 + 255; //overflows
    i = 100 + int.MaxValue+100; // works

}
```

1) Is the reason why b expression (`b = 255 + 255;`) causes an overflow error due to being affected by two conflicting rules, where first rule **R1** states:

> A constant-expression (§7.19) of type
>   int can be converted to type sbyte,
>   byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong,
>   provided the value of the
>   constant-expression is within the
>   range of the destination type.

while second rule **R2** states that within unchecked context overflow is allowed.

And in the case of b expression, **R1** takes precedence over **R2**, and thus since constant expression `255+ 255` is not within the range of destination type ( which is byte ), **R1** causes an error, even though **R2** permits an overflow?

2)

a) Here's my reasoning as to why i expression (`i = 100 + int.MaxValue+100;`) doesn't cause an error:

1 - When compiler starts computing i expression, it doesn't try to promote values `100` and `int.MaxValue` to type `long` before performing the addition ( thus during the computation process the two values are still of type `int` )

2 - the addition does cause an overflow, but since this happens within unchecked context, no error is thrown

3 - Since the two values didn't get promoted to `long`, the resulting value is also of type `int` and as such the resulting value is within the range of destination type

b) But if instead compiler did promote `100` and `int.MaxValue`; to type `long` before performing the addition, then i expression would cause an error due to violation of rule **R1**?!

thanx

Comment: Interesting analysis - What is the question?

Comment: The question is whether my reasoning is correct :)

Comment: Aside from incorrectly describing the rules as "conflicting", your analysis is correct. Why do you believe these rules to be in conflict? It's not that rule 1 "takes precedence" over the other. Both rules apply equally. "byte b = 510;" is illegal whether the context is checked or unchecked.

Comment: R2 rule allows expressions to overflow and thus if it wasn't for R1, b expression would also be allowed to overflow. Hence, I assumed the two rules are in conflict. Unless, if R2 explicitly states what type of overflows it allows and thus if it doesn't mention b expression type of overflow, then I guess the two rules aren't in conflict?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The constants are all `int` by default, so the second statement will overflow happily and stay within int. You can see that it fails if you make one of the constants long:

```
byte b;
int i;

unchecked
{
    b = 255 + 255; //overflows
    i = 100L + int.MaxValue+100; // fails as well
}
```

Comment: So I was correct in assuming that b expression causes an error due to rule R1 taking precedence over R2?

Comment: Yes. In the case of `i` no conversion happens, so rule **R1** does not apply at all.

Answer (score 1):

With the byte you are adding to integers, and then converting to a byte, thus causing an overflow when converting(implicitly).
With integers overflows just resets to start from int.MinValue, so the result would be `int i = int.MinValue + 199;`

EDIT:
The following is though possible

```
 byte b1 = (byte)255;
 byte b2 = (byte)255;
 byte b = (byte)(b1 + b2);
```

That is because both numbers are stored as bytes, and the sum is converted in runtime which would not make a constant expression (as b1 and b2 is not known as constants by the compiler).

Comment: This is not quite correct. `byte b = (byte)(b1 + b2);` can be done because you are explicitly casting `int` to `byte`. If you remove the explicit cast then you will find that the compiler complains because adding two bytes results in an `int`. You can do `byte b = (byte)(255 + 255)` just as well. I was a bit suprised though that the compiler did not optimize the `b1 + b2` to `510`. Maybe something left to the JIT.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is that the following code is still "within the range of the destination type"

```
i = 100 + int.MaxValue + 100
```

After the overflow, i will evaluate to -2147483449 which is a valid integer.

When adding 255 to 255, the result is 510 (an integer) which is well outside the valid range for the byte type.  No overflow happens here.

Hope that helps